# Elegant way to filter a complex array of objects

Tags: c#, linq, powershell

So I have an object with the following properties in PowerShell (this is its JSON representation containing only one item):

```
        "NetworkResourcePermittedUsers": [
          {
            "PermittedUser": {
              "UserName": "somedomain\\someuser"
            },
            "SecurityAccessLevel": {
              "Level": "Read"
            },
            "SecurityAccessMode": {
              "Mode": "Allow"
            }
          }
        ]
```

What I want to do is to filter my `NetworkResourcePermittedUsers` array based on the `Level` field inside `SecurityAccessLevel`, so basically: `SecurityAccessLevel.Level`

In LINQ I would do something like:

```
networkResourcePermittedUsers.Any(x => x.SecurityAccessLevel.Level.Equals("myvalue"))
```

I know that in PowerShell I can use something like:

```
$networkResourcePermittedUsers -contains "value"
```

But in this case, the `-contains` parameter assumes that I have an array composed of value objects (`string`, `int`, etc)

So is there a way to use the `-contains` parameter to filter a complex object graph??

something like:

```
#this is bad code -- doesn't work
$networkResourcePermittedUsers -contains "myvalue" -path SecurityAccessLevel.Level
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the -contains operator, but you can use a pipeline that is similar to LINQ:

```
$networkResourcePermittedUsers | Where-Object {
    $_.SecurityAccessLevel.Level -eq 'myvalue' }
```